# Pass argument to reduce_C_function in matplotlib hexbin plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to implement a hexbin plot inside a function, and have a rather complicated `reduce_C_function` that will need to receive an argument `a`. An (albeit trivial) example:

```
    def sum_i(z,a):
        return a*np.sum(z)
    def some_function(X,Y,Z,a):
        hexb = plt.hexbin(X,Y,C=Z,reduce_C_function=sum_i)
```

Now, the matplotlib documentation (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hexbin.html) is not exactly very informative on the use of the `reduce_C_function`, so how can I manage to pass `a` on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function from your `sum_i` and pass it to `plt.hexbin` as a function of a single argument:

```
from functools import partial

def sum_i(z,a):
    return a*np.sum(z)
def some_function(X,Y,Z,a):
    reduce_function = partial(sum_i, a=a)
    hexb = plt.hexbin(X,Y,C=Z,reduce_C_function=reduce_function)
```

From the looks of the [source code](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/axes/_axes.html#Axes.hexbin) there is no other way to pass additional arguments for `reduce_C_function`.